# UDP file transferring in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am writing a program to transfer files through a lan computers, it's been a while I'm searching for file transferring methods in Delphi. I found UDP is a good solution, but there is a problem: in every example or article I found there was a client program beside a server program, but my program have to send and receive to/from every computer in network, there is no specific server or client, something like p2p, I don't want to make a computer Server and another one Client, what should I do? I searched Indy articles too, it's working in Server/Client mode too (as far as I found).

[image]

Comment: this does not mean you have to programms, just you need to have two components in your programm e.g.  TIdUDPClient +  TIdUDPServer.

Comment: Your question is unclear, though - if you want to send files using UDP, something has to be at the other end waiting to receive them. If you're just wanting to copy files, there's no need for UDP or anything else; you can just copy the files between machines. Can you explain exactly what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: @Ken, i want to Send (and as u said in every send something have to wait at the other end) and problem is exactly here for me too, its not always "computer_A" send and "computer_B" receive, sometimes "B" sends and "A" receives and sometimes "C" sends and "B" receives,.... so i cant say "A" always listen and "B" always send, situation will change.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with UDP? Do you specifically need something that UDP offers (like Broadcast capability)? For certain applications UDP is the better choice over TCP (example: VoIP) because it lacks transmission-control and network lag and jitter can be handled by the application, but for file transfer you *need* a transmission control protocol. If you do it over UDP, you'll surely re-implement the whole TCP thing yourself!

Comment: @Cosmin, it was a great tip, thanks. No, there is no specific need with UDP, in my searches i found it simpler to handle. what do you suggest? TCP with Indy? does it serve what i need (diagram image i placed is what im looking for)

Comment: @Armin, UDP is simpler to handle if you only need to send/receive very small amounts of data and can live with the UDP limitation: there's *no* guarantee that the packet you're sending makes it to destination, there's no way to check that it did (unless you have the receiver send back a confirmation), but that starts sounding like poor-man's TCP. You should use Indy and you should start with something simple. I'd go higher-level, implement things using the HTTP protocol: that way you can use a Browser to check your application.

Comment: @Armin, your network diagram looks scary, but it's nothing special. In the end you can decompose everything to just two computers that might talk to one-another; Your diagram only shows that one computer might talk to 5 others, but it's the same thing done 5 times. Even the one relation between two computers can be decomposed into a client-server scenario. One computer requests a file from the other, and that's it. You can reduce the "send" file scenario to a "request" scenario as well: Have the sending computer ask the other one to request the file from itself!

Comment: @Armin: being able to receive a message, each computer have to listen on certain port. Including sending computer.

Comment: @Cosmin - i experienced data broken with HTTP and FTP, so i would not claim TCP is very reliable. I think if author wants to make P2P - he shoudl do like all modern P2P does. Split data to small hierrchical chunks and use TigerTree Hash to control transmission. Whether the main carrier be UDP, TCP or even HTTP (like in G2 P2P)  would have little difference then.

Comment: I searched for Indy transfering and used it (idTCPSever and idTCPClient) for file transfering, im sending a file from client (idTCPClient) to server (idTCPServer), i want to know is it possible to send a file from server to client too? or i have to use both idTCPServer and idTCPClient in each program to send and receive files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Indy's `TIdTrivialFTP` and `TIdTrivialFTPServer` components.  [TFTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) is a UDP-based file transfer protocol.

Comment: FTP has nothing to do with multicast. And TFTP neither. TFTP is just a dead simple one to one protocol, very slow (waiting for a ACK on any packet) and meant for low hardware resources. Nothing to do with OP question. TCP/IP or even HTTP (as OCI 7 layer) are much more reliable than TFTP, since they feature windowing, packet resend, and a lot of other reliable transmission means.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: Nothing in the OP's question or comments lead me to think that broadcasting or multicasting is actually desired. That is something you assumed and the OP did not confirm. What the OP actually described is how many P2Ps actually work. Peers decide who is "client" and who is "server" and can swap roles when needed, but each individual file transfer is still a client/server model in one direction or the other. UDP protocols like TFTP, and TCP protocols like FTP and HTTP, work fine for that. I did not say TFTP was efficient, just possible given the OP's initial desire to use UDP.

Comment: @Remy, im so newbie to net programming, can you show me an example link of these components usage?

Comment: Using FTP for inter process communication, whereas it is a remote file  access protocol? Pretty strange option, AFAIK. A RESTful/HTTP protocol make better sense, IMHO - or even plain TCP/IP with a dedicated application layer. If you look at the OP diagram, sounds just like a multicast to me... every node is sending to every other nodes... even if of course, for the transport layer, it is always point to point.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: what the OP described is not a broadcast. He said "A sends to B", "B sends to A", "C sends to B". He did not say "A sends to everyone", "B sends to everyone", etc.

Comment: Op did not know about broadcasting, but explicitly wanted " my program have to send and receive to/from every computer in network". What is it but multicast? Of course, op's comment is confusing, and his question was pretty unclear. In practice, p2p softwares use both broadcast and client server, and are much more complex than basic file transfer.

Answer (score 6):

UDP can work in *broadcast* mode, which is what you need. But such UDP broadcasts are *not routable outside the current network* (i.e. they are blocked by routers), so you have to implement something more complex if your project needs to be accessible outside the primary physical network.

Do not reinvent the wheel! If you want to see some working source implementing this concept, see *Ares Galaxy*:

> "Delphi self-organizing p2p network project featuring high scale
>   capability and fast broadcast-type search system. Client supports
>   multi-source file transfers, partial file sharing, built-in
>   audio/video player and decentralized chat rooms".

The [source code files are available from SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aresgalaxy/files/aresgalaxy/). You could re-use/adapt the P2P network layer for your needs - but take attention to the license terms of Ares source code, if you use it in your projects.

Comment: Of course it does work in multicast mode, over UDP. But not also, since it is able to build a TCP/IP P2P distributed network.